# grid json data without records attribute

Tags: jquery, w2ui

I was going through w2ui grid with loading json data.
Most of the grid-json examples it shows the json data with records attributes.
Please find the code below. 
**http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!grid/grid-1**

My requirement is I will be getting the json data from server which is created by different system
I cannot directly edit that.

I tried without using records attribute. It is not working. 
Is there any alternate way of doing without including the records attribute in json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At **Line # 1815** of library (version 1.4.3) you can see that `var records = method.records;` which clearly shows that library is assuming when you call its function **w2grid** you must pass data in **records** attribute.
In my opinion it would be better to create an object with **records** attribute and assign your json data to it